# Custom CSS file is not getting applied (in Angular Application)

Tags: html, css

I'm unable to get a custom CSS sheet to work in the navigation bar. I've an angular application, where I'm adding a CSS file to override the anchor tag colors inside the navbar. Since the freelancer css files I'm using have made the anchor tag white in color, and there's a place in the Nav bar HTML, where I want to use anchor tag in a readable color, I've written custom CSS file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="jargoViewer">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>Jargo Foods Pvt Ltd.</title>

        <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Theme CSS -->
        <link href="css/freelancer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Jargo CSS Styles -->
        <link href="css/jargo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-loading-bar/0.9.0/loading-bar.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />


        <!--
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
          <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-loading-bar/0.9.0/loading-bar.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
          <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-loading-bar/0.9.0/loading-bar.min.js'></script>
          <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        -->

        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="bower_components/jquery.easing/js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
        <script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>
        <script src="js/freelancer.min.js"></script>

        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="RestService.js"></script>
        <script src="UserCart.js"></script>
        <script src="ProdSearchService.js"></script>
        <script src="ProductsSearchController.js"></script>
        <script src="MainController.js"></script>
        <script src="ProductController.js"></script>
        <script src="NavController.js"></script>
        <script src="CheckoutController.js"></script>
        <script src="PaymentController.js"></script>
        <script src="LoginModal.js"></script>
        <script src="LoginModalCtrl.js"></script>
        <script src="LoginService.js"></script>
        <script src="CheckoutPaymentService.js"></script>
        <script src="OrdersController.js"></script>
        <script src="SessionInterceptor.js"></script>

        <!-- Payment Gateway Lib -->
        <script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body id="page-top" class="index">
        <div id="skipnav"><a href="#maincontent">Skip to main content</a></div>
        <!-- Add the Navigation Bar on top -->
        <div ng-include="'nav.html'"></div>
        <!-- This is where the Actual Content would go -->
        <div ng-view autoscroll="true"></div>
        <!-- Add the footer at bottom -->
        <div ng-include="'footer.html'"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

My CSS file is as follows (jargo.css). Notice the use of a new class called **cart-table-link**:

```
.cart-table-link a{
    color: #FF8B03 !important;
}
.cart-table-link li a{
  color: #FF8B03;
}
.cart-table-link li a:hover{
  color: #18BC9C;
}
.cart-table-link li a:focus,
.cart-table-link li a:active{
  color: #FF8B03;
}
.cart-table-link li.active a{
  color: #FF8B03;
  background: #18BC9C;
}
.cart-table-link li.active a:hover,
.cart-table-link li.active a:focus,
.cart-table-link li.active a:active{
  color: #FF8B03;
  background: #18BC9C;
}
```

My portion of nav.html, which contains a DropDown "Cart" Nav Element, which when clicked opens a Table with row entries for each product in the Cart, and finally, at the end, a "View Cart" and a "Checkout" anchor element. Each row entry in the Cart table contains an anchor tag with name of the Product Item, which if clicked should take user to the Product details page. Below is nav.html:

```
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <!--<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom"> -->
     <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-custom">
        <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller = "NavController">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">Jargo Foods</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#/main#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#/main#portfolio">Products</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#/main#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="#/main#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <!-- Search Starts -->
                    <li>
                        <!--
                        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
                        -->
                        <div>
                            <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" ng-model = "searchtext" class="form-control"  placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term"/>
                                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button ng-click = "search()" class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <!-- Cart Starts -->
                    <!--<div class="navbar-brand navbar-right">-->
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Cart
                            <span id="cart-total" ng-show ="userCart.cart_size">{{userCart.cart_size}} item(s)</span>
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                          <!--
                                          <div >{{userCart.cart_products}}</div>
                                          <div class="row" ng-repeat="obj in userCart.cart_prod_ids">{{obj}}</div>

                                          <div class="row" ng-repeat="(id, obj) in userCart.cart_products">{{id}} {{obj}}</div>
                                          -->
                             <li>
                                              <!--
                                              <table class="table table-striped hcart">
                                              -->
                                  <table>
                                      <tbody>
                                          <tr ng-repeat="(id, itemObj) in userCart.cart_products">
                                              <td class="text-center">
                                                  <a ng-href="#/product/{{itemObj.ID}}">
                                                      <img src="img/others/cart.png" alt="image" title="image" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive"/>
                                                  </a>
                                              </td>
                                              <td class="text-left" class="col-md-2">
                                                  <a class="cart-table-link" ng-href="#/product/{{itemObj.ID}}">{{itemObj.ItemName}}</a>
                                              </td>
                                              <td class="text-right">x {{itemObj.Quantity}}</td>
                                              <td class="text-right">₹ {{itemObj.Quantity * itemObj.CostPerUnit}}</td>
                                              <td class="text-center">
                                                 <i class="fa fa-times" ng-click = "remInCart(itemObj.ID, 1)" ></i>
                                              </td>
                                          </tr  >
                                      </tbody>
                                  </table>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                  <table class="table table-bordered total">
                                      <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                              <td class="text-right"><strong>Sub-Total</strong></td>
                                              <td class="text-left">₹ {{userCart.cart_val}}</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                              <td class="text-right"><strong>VAT (5.5%)</strong></td>
                                              <td class="text-left">₹ {{userCart.cart_val * 0.055  | number:2}}</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                                <td class="text-right"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                                                <td class="text-left">₹ {{userCart.cart_val * 1.055 | number:2}}</td>
                                          </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                  </table>
                             </li>
                             <li>
                                 <p class="text-right btn-block1">
                                     <a href="#/cart" class ="cart-table-link">View Cart</a>
                                     <a class = "button cart-table-link" href="#/checkout">Checkout</a>
                                 </p>
                             </li>
                         </ul>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </nav> <!-- /.container-fluid -->
```

Just search for the reference to the **cart-table-link** in the nav.html file.

Despite the above changes, the cart-table-link CSS is most likely not even recognized. Notice the image (chrome inspection)

[image]

Any clue where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS is not correct.
The class cart-table-link **is** the **a** element.

```css
a.cart-table-link {
color: #FF8B03;
}
```

I removed also the !important because having a.cart-table-link will have more hierarchy than the other styles that I saw.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by cart-table-link is the a element? What did my implemented class CSS mean?

Comment: Also, how do I define .cart-table-link li a:hover{
  color: #18BC9C;
}